# How to select element in jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing small js app and I got stucked. I have multiple divs called `line` inside each line I have another two divs called `inner-line1` and `inner-line2` 
What I'm trying to achieve is: for Each `line` I want to select its children.

I have tried to use jQuery.each() method however when I try to select the children It always select all `inner-line1` and `inner-line2` so how can I select only current children?

Please take look at my JsFiddle for better understanding. Thank you

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/772413/)

```js
let element = $('.inner-line');
element.each(function() {
  line1 = $('.inner-line1');
  line2 = $('.inner-line2');
  console.log(line1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line">
  <div class="inner-line1"></div>
  <div class="inner-line2"></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div class="inner-line1"></div>
  <div class="inner-line2"></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div class="inner-line1"></div>
  <div class="inner-line2"></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div class="inner-line1"></div>
  <div class="inner-line2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited, thanks for telling me :)

Comment: I would suggest having a read of the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com. Even just reading the method names are self-explanatory, such as `children()` and `find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.line').each(function (i, l) {
 //in this point, you had been taken all ".inner-line1"s in your document.  change it to this:
 let line1 = $(l).children('.inner-line1');
 let line2 = $(l).children('.inner-line2');

 console.log(line1);
 console.log(line2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i usually use find while looping to select any child element

```
    $('.line').each(function () {
       var child = $(this).find('.inner-line1');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` function.

```
let element = $('.line');
element.each(function (e,i) {

    let $line1 = $(i).find('.inner-line1');
    let $line2 = $(i).find('.inner-line2');
    console.log($line1);
    //console.log($line2);

});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xq58p2j/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can try 'children' function.
let element = $('.line');
let line1,line2;
element.each(function () {
    const $this = $(this);

    line1 = $this.children('.inner-line1');
    line2 = $this.children('.inner-line2');

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.